# Variables from makefile to bash

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have next situation:
source of **test.mk**:

> test_var := test_me

source of **test.sh**:

```
$test_var = some method that get test_var from .mk
if [ "$test_var" = "test_me" ] ; then    
   do something
fi
```

How can I get variable from `.mk` file to my `.sh` file, without `grep + sed` and other parsing techniques.

**EDIT**
I can't change `.mk` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you can't use `sed` or `grep`, then you'll have to read the makefile database after parsing using something like:

```
make -pn -f test.mk > /tmp/make.db.txt 2>/dev/null
while read var assign value; do
    if [[ ${var} = 'test_var' ]] && [[ ${assign} = ':=' ]]; then
        test_var="$value"
        break
    fi
done </tmp/make.db.txt
rm -f /tmp/make.db.txt
```

this makes sure that something like:

```
value := 12345
test_var := ${value}
```

will output `12345`, instead of `${value}`

If you wanted to create variables representing all those from the makefile, you can change the inner if to:

```
if [[ ${assign} = ':=' ]]; then
    # any variables containing . are replaced with _
    eval ${var//./_}=\"$value\"
fi
```

so you will get variables like `test_var` set to the appropriate value. There are some make variables that start with `.`, which would need to be replaced with a shell-variable safe value like `_`, which is what the search-replace is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Create a makefile on the fly to load the `test.mk` file and print the variable:

```
value=$(make -f - 2>/dev/null <<\EOF
include test.mk
all:
    @echo $(test_var)
EOF
)

echo "The value is $value"
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a rule `print_var` in your makefile with the following code:

```
print_var:
        echo $(test_var)
```

And in your `test.sh`, do:

```
 $test_var = $(make print_var)
```

You also have to consider to put `print_var` rule in `.PHONY` section

Comment: I cant edit makefile, i EDIT my post, sorry I forget wrote about it.

Comment: @Pepelac Than you have to parse your makefile.

Comment: Are you shure that it's only one way?

Answer (score 2):

A variation of @Idelic answer I came up some time ago on my own:

```
function get_make_var()
{
    echo 'unique123:;@echo ${'"$1"'}' | 
      make -f - -f "$2" --no-print-directory unique123
}

test_var=`get_make_var test_var test.mk`
```

It uses the lesser known feature of the GNU make - ability to read multiple `Makefile`s from the command line using multiple `-f` options.

Comment: This is the most consistent answer since make is quite complex to parse and mechanisms like secondary expansion can lead to undesired results. But I want to point the importance of **choosing a target name unique enough** opposing to @Idelic 's answer.